# IE8 Overflow hidden in table

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

http://jsfiddle.net/zWfac/
Can't make this code work for IE8, any help would be trully apreciated. (The intention is if the text exceeds the max width it shall be hidden and shown in a tooltip at hover)

```
td, th
{
    width: 65px;
    max-width: 65px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Placing `position: relative` as stated in many other post doesn't do anything.
Placing `position: absolute` in the parent and `position: relative` in the child as stated in some other post also doesn't do anything.
Also, as expected `max-width: 65px;` also never works.

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript?

Comment: i think m gonna mark as duplicate as there are a lot question with same issue..

Comment: most of those suposed duplicates state the solution is add position:relative but if you try, it doesn't work

Comment: The rest of the supposed duplicates say that `width` is treated as `min-width` in table cells, and if you really want to restrict the width, make sure the _content_ is not wider than 65px. In other words, put a `div` or whatever in each table cell and apply the styles to them.

Comment: Thats basicly saying that if everything you got is a hammer all problems are nails. Obviously if I adulter the fields to fit the table It would generate other redundant issues like I will have to implement other solutions to for example submit the form the table is in.

Comment: @balmungX Oh, sorry, I didn't know there were specific restrictions to the possible solution of the problem. You didn't say so in the question. So basically you don't want to change the HTML, is that right?